# Unable to place condition for a server response in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift

Here I am getting response as **String** (true or false) from the server by using this I need to place a condition like if `jsonObj` is true then it need to perform some thing if not it should perform a different thing but here after placing a condition it shows an error that `Binary operator cannot be applied to operands of type 'String' and 'Bool'` shown in this line `if jsonObj == true{` can anyone help me how to place condition to check whether it is true or false ?

```
func customerItemsDeleteDownloadJsonWithURL(customerItemsAPI: String){
   let url = URL(string: customerItemsAPI)
   var request = URLRequest(url: url! as URL)
   request.httpMethod = "DELETE"
   request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
   request.addValue("Bearer \(self.customerKeyToken!)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
   let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
   if error != nil { print(error!); return }
   do {
         if let jsonObj = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8) {
                print(jsonObj)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if jsonObj == true{

                        }
                        else{

                        }
                    }
               }
           }
           catch {
               print(error)
          }
     }
     task.resume()
}
```

Comment: Binary operator cannot be applied to operands of type 'String' and 'Bool' means you are checking string with boolean value. If jsonObj is always a string then  you try in this way if jsonObj == "true"

Comment: You should serialize the data as a dictionay or array as per your response. You are making it string and you are trying to use it as a Boolean. Something like this :                 let dicResponse = try? JSONSerialization .jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! NSDictionary

Comment: it is string that to. with true or false as response not any dictionary or array @sharadchauhan

Comment: @user4261201 Then how can you say its JSON ? if its a string then compare String. Like  user4261201  said.

Comment: @sharadchauhan we can observe from this line " if let jsonObj = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8) " that jsonObj is String

Comment: @User can you please update the question with jsonObject. I mean the output of this line print(jsonObj). So that we get more clarity on the jsonObj

Comment: @user4261201 Yes I agree."Here I am getting the Json response as true or false", So I thought its JSON response.

Comment: json response is `true` @user4261201

Comment: Please post the result of `print(data! as NSData)`

Comment: every time when you get response from server you got the status code use status code if status code is 200 its mean your call is succeeded @User

Comment: `print(data! as NSData)` the output for this is  `<74727565>` and the output of `print(jsonObj)` is `true` @vadian

Answer (score 1):

According to the `Data` output the response is a simple `String` rather than `JSON`, `Bool` or other numeric representations.

So just add double quotes.

```
if jsonObj == "true" { ...
```

Side note: There is not need to dispatch this comparison to the main thread.